# Returning pair from a function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, return, std-pair

I am a beginner in C++ and I faced the following problem:
In my program I have a function to which I pass an array with fixed size as a parameter. I iterate through it and perform some operations. As a result I have 2 variables - `br` and `a`, which I want to return from the function. I create a pair and assign to it these values. However when I run the whole program the compiler throws an error - cannot convert std::pair<> to int. I would like to ask why this happens?

```
 #include <utility>
  using namespace std;
  pair <double,double> rez;
  //int main() ...
   double sumaf(int k[20])
{

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        if(k[i]>0 && k[i]%3==0)
        {
            a+=k[i];
            br++;
        }
    }

    rez.first=a;
    rez.second=br;
    return rez;

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your declared function return type should match the actual return type

Comment: You are declaring your sumaf function to return a double instead of std::pair<double,double>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the return type of `sumaf()`.

Also, there is no need for a global variable (`rez`).

```
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

pair<double, double> sumaf(int k[20])
{
    double a = 0,
           br = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        if (k[i] > 0 && k[i] % 3 == 0)
        {
            a += k[i];
            br++;
        }
    }
    return make_pair(a, br);
}
```